# How to properly select a value from items.index ingested as json

Tags: react-native

I am trying to select the twitter value (if present) from an social accounts array. When value !='' I want the View to show. I am not certain about the code below.

I have also tried to change the '' to a null but same result

getting the value:

```
listing_data._links.length != 0 && listing_data._links.map((item,index) => {
      item.network == 'Twitter' ? this.twitter = item.url : '' })
```

showing the result:

```
{twitter != '' && (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.9}
              onPress={() => this.openTweet(twitter)}
              style={styles.row}>
              <Image style={styles.imageIcon} source={Images.icons.iconTweet} />
              <Text style={styles.label}>{Languages.twitter}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{twitter}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
```

I expect the label not to show if the value of post.twitter = ''

Answer (score 1):

You can check by tripple equals

```
post.twitter === ''
```

also you can check the value exist on not in json object

```
yourJson.hasOwnProperty('param name')
```

Comment: Hi, I have const twitter = post.twitter passed before the render part. I suspect it is in the mapping code because I am getting e.g. website address also from the json with this.company_website = listing_data._job_website
        ? listing_data._job_website
        : '' and that works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and happy to share it here:

instead of

```
const twitter = post.twitter
```

I had to initialize it like:

```
const twitter = post.twitter === undefined ? '' : post.twitter
```

in that way the View works perfectly.